# big array of Button and textview in a single screen

Tags: android, arrays, button, textview

I would like to implement an application to store information about the content of freezer.
The first layout that I've developped is 5 "floor" , in any floor there are 12 Button and 12 TextView,but the result is 12x5= 60 button and 60 textview.

[image: layout]
I think that this layout have to much resource...or not?
The code is more simple to implement, but te performance are bad!( I think).

this are the code for the first implementation:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/a9p_09_11_00943" >

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:columnCount="8"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:rowCount="4" >

            <!-- prima riga  P1 R1 -->

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnP1C1R1"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:background="@drawable/add_64" android:contentDescription="@string/store_add" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnP1C2R1"
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:background="@drawable/add_64" android:contentDescription="@string/store_add"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnP1C3R1"
                android:layout_column="5"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:background="@drawable/add_64" android:contentDescription="@string/store_add" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtP1C1R1"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size_txt_view"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:text="@string/store_void"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtP1C2R1"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size_txt_view"
                android:layout_column="4"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:text="@string/store_void"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtP1C3R1"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size_txt_view"
                android:layout_column="6"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:text="@string/store_void"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <!-- seconda riga  P1 R2 -->

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnP1C1R2"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:background="@drawable/add_64" android:contentDescription="@string/store_add" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnP1C2R2"
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:background="@drawable/add_64" android:contentDescription="@string/store_add" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnP1C3R2"
                android:layout_column="5"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:background="@drawable/add_64" android:contentDescription="@string/store_add" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtP1C1R2"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size_txt_view"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:text="@string/store_void"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtP1C2R2"
                android:layout_column="4"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size_txt_view"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:text="@string/store_void"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtP1C3R2"
                android:layout_column="6"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size_txt_view"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:text="@string/store_void"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <!-- seconda riga  P1 R3 -->

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnP1C1R3"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:background="@drawable/add_64" android:contentDescription="@string/store_add" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnP1C2R3"
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:background="@drawable/add_64" android:contentDescription="@string/store_add" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnP1C3R3"
                android:layout_column="5"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:background="@drawable/add_64" android:contentDescription="@string/store_add" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtP1C1R3"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size_txt_view"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:text="@string/store_void"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtP1C2R3"
                android:layout_column="4"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size_txt_view"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:text="@string/store_void"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtP1C3R3"
                android:layout_column="6"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size_txt_view"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:text="@string/store_void"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <!-- seconda riga  P1 R4 -->

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnP1C1R4"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:background="@drawable/add_64" android:contentDescription="@string/store_add" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnP1C2R4"
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:background="@drawable/add_64" android:contentDescription="@string/store_add" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnP1C3R4"
                android:layout_column="5"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:background="@drawable/add_64" android:contentDescription="@string/store_add" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtP1C1R4"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size_txt_view"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:text="@string/store_void"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtP1C2R4"
                android:layout_column="4"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size_txt_view"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:text="@string/store_void"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtP1C3R4"
                android:layout_column="6"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size_txt_view"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:text="@string/store_void"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/store_4" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/store_3" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/store_2" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/store_1" />
        </GridLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

**The second Idea** is a custom ListView.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/a9p_09_11_00943">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >
        </ListView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The custom item have inside 12 buttom and 12 textview, like that:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/a9p_09_11_00943" >

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:columnCount="8"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:rowCount="4" >

            <!-- prima riga  P1 R1 -->

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnP1C1R1"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:background="@drawable/add_64" android:contentDescription="@string/store_add" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnP1C2R1"
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:background="@drawable/add_64" android:contentDescription="@string/store_add"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnP1C3R1"
                android:layout_column="5"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:background="@drawable/add_64" android:contentDescription="@string/store_add" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtP1C1R1"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size_txt_view"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:text="@string/store_void"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtP1C2R1"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size_txt_view"
                android:layout_column="4"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:text="@string/store_void"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtP1C3R1"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size_txt_view"
                android:layout_column="6"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:text="@string/store_void"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <!-- seconda riga  P1 R2 -->

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnP1C1R2"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:background="@drawable/add_64" android:contentDescription="@string/store_add" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnP1C2R2"
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:background="@drawable/add_64" android:contentDescription="@string/store_add" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnP1C3R2"
                android:layout_column="5"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:background="@drawable/add_64" android:contentDescription="@string/store_add" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtP1C1R2"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size_txt_view"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:text="@string/store_void"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtP1C2R2"
                android:layout_column="4"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size_txt_view"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:text="@string/store_void"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtP1C3R2"
                android:layout_column="6"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size_txt_view"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:text="@string/store_void"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <!-- seconda riga  P1 R3 -->

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnP1C1R3"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:background="@drawable/add_64" android:contentDescription="@string/store_add" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnP1C2R3"
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:background="@drawable/add_64" android:contentDescription="@string/store_add" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnP1C3R3"
                android:layout_column="5"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:background="@drawable/add_64" android:contentDescription="@string/store_add" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtP1C1R3"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size_txt_view"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:text="@string/store_void"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtP1C2R3"
                android:layout_column="4"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size_txt_view"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:text="@string/store_void"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtP1C3R3"
                android:layout_column="6"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size_txt_view"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:text="@string/store_void"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <!-- seconda riga  P1 R4 -->

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnP1C1R4"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:background="@drawable/add_64" android:contentDescription="@string/store_add" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnP1C2R4"
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:background="@drawable/add_64" android:contentDescription="@string/store_add" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnP1C3R4"
                android:layout_column="5"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:background="@drawable/add_64" android:contentDescription="@string/store_add" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtP1C1R4"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size_txt_view"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:text="@string/store_void"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtP1C2R4"
                android:layout_column="4"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size_txt_view"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:text="@string/store_void"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtP1C3R4"
                android:layout_column="6"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size_txt_view"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:text="@string/store_void"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/store_4" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/store_3" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/store_2" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/store_1" />
        </GridLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and I have the possibility to add a lot of floor, more that 5!
But there are a lot of difficulty to implement the code:
1) when the user click on the item (freezer floor) how can implement the **button.setOnClickListener** for all the 12 button?

2)the performance of **getView** inside the adapter are fast or slow?

Another idea is create 5 Fragment, and inside every Fragment build a xml whith 12 button and 12 textview.
Is possible this idea or is more complicated?
any other idea?
thanks.

**EDIT**

I have tried another way, by inflating dinamically the xml:

the container:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout0"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>
```

the code:

```
private static final int[] BUTTON_IDS_P1 = {
            R.id.btnP1C1R1,
            R.id.btnP1C1R2, 
            R.id.btnP1C1R3,
            R.id.btnP1C1R4,
            R.id.btnP1C2R1,
            R.id.btnP1C2R2, 
            R.id.btnP1C2R3,
            R.id.btnP1C2R4,
            R.id.btnP1C3R1,
            R.id.btnP1C3R2,
            R.id.btnP1C3R3,
            R.id.btnP1C3R4
        };

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                        final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) appContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                        View child =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.ripiano_frigo, null);
                        child.setId(i);
                        lLayout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout0);
                        lLayout.addView(child);
    buttons = new ArrayList<ImageButton>(BUTTON_IDS_P1.length);
                    int idt=0;
                    for(int id : BUTTON_IDS_P1) {
                        ImageButton button = (ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(id);
                        //button.setOnClickListener(this); // maybe
                        MyTag myTag = new MyTag(idt, id,TEXTVIEW_IDS_P1[idt++], 0, 0);
                        button.setTag(myTag);

                        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
}
```

all is Ok for the first group of button (12), but how configure the other? which is the ID of the second group of button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create the layout with first floor and inflate the  layout dynamically and create floors .

Comment: I think to understand your answer, I have to create the first set of button (first floor) with the xml code, and then inflate this layout dinamically? How do that? in the second floor (created dinamically) can I have the onclick for the button?

Comment: create a method in that inflate a layout and write onclick listner to the buttons  and call that method how many floors you want.